# Guidance: Want to develop an application which will convert a website into mobile app

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I am working on a project which will convert a website into mobile application. I tried creating it this way -> check the image at the link: [Website to Mobile App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1EEK.png)

However by this method, I am only able to open the website like in my mobile via my app. This looks similar to how to you open the website in google chrome in full desktop view. However this is not what I want. I want to develop an app like how Youtube has actually has an app on playstore.

Can anybody guide me over how to begin with it?

Best Regards,
Code Funda

Comment: Fund, For that you need to use API of that website

Answer (score -1):

**Hello, I just work same as you so this is the code of mine. I hope It will help you**

**and you can see code here => Link:**  http://www.androidcodinghub.com/2017/04/youtube-in-webview.html

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String stringUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/";
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = "YoutubeActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        getUI();
    }

    private void getUI() {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().getBuiltInZoomControls();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().getDefaultFontSize();
        webView.getSettings().supportZoom();
        webView.loadUrl(stringUrl);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    }

    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onReceivedError: " + error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Komal,
Thanks for the help!

Actually even my code is giving the same output as yours. But the way I want is that I should be able to control independent sections of the website and place them in my app as per the code of my program. However currently what seems to be happening is that because Youtube has a mobile friendly format of its site, its showing that. Everything is automatically placed pre-programmed instead my control over the sections.

Comment: What I need is I should be able to redesign the look of Youtube in my app.

If you look at the left of Youtube website view, then you will find the sections like
Music, Sports, Movies, News and more.

I should be able to arrange videos in the section format as shown below:

Music (5 videos in this section)
Sports (5 videos here)
Movies (5 videos here)
News (5 videos here)
TV Shows (5 videos here)
Sports (5 videos here)

And these sections should get auto-updated as and when new videos appear on top of youtube in these sections